# How to call the same method on all data member variables using a fluent interface

Tags: php, arrays

I have a class like this:

```
class example{

    private $foo  = array();
    private $bar  = array();

    public function getFoo(){
        return $this->foo;
    }

    public function getBar(){
        return $this->bar;
    }

    //for example
    public function doSomth(array $smth){
        // do somth on $smth 
        return $smth;
    }
}
```

I want to be able to define a method that works on all data members of my class which they have the type of array, somthing like this:

```
$exmpl = new Example();
$exmpl->getFoo()->doSmth();
//or
$exmpl->getBar()->doSmth();
```

What should I do?

Comment: I don't see where the problem is and what exactly you want to do here? Maybe you can add a concrete example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of returning `$this->foo` or `$this->bar` directly, return an object that takes the data and has a `doSmth` method, like:

```
class example{
    private $foo  = array();
    private $bar  = array();

    public function getFoo(){
        return new dosmth($this->foo);
    }

    public function getBar(){
        return new dosmth($this->bar);
    }
}

class dosmth {
    public function __construct(array $smth) {
        $this->smth = $smth;
    }
    public function doSmth() {
        echo 'do something on $this->smth';
        return $this->smth;
    }
    private $smth;
}

$exmpl = new Example();
$exmpl->getFoo()->doSmth();
$exmpl->getBar()->doSmth();
```

See also [Fluent Interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface).

While this appears to solve the problem as stated, I caution that there may be a better design approach. Specifically, let "example" be purely a data container with accessor methods for "foo" and "bar", and let "dosmth" be a helper class that you instantiate and call as needed. This would be an equivalent API invocation that is only marginally more typing but keeps the concerns clearly separated between classes:

```
$helper = new dosmth;
$exmpl  = new example;
$helper->doSmth($exmpl->getFoo());
$helper->doSmth($exmpl->getBar());
```

Fluent interfaces are a siren song. Use them where they help, but don't implement them just because you can.